# Setting up WSO2ESB to send messages to WSO2MB

Tags: smooks, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I am trying to get our proxy in wso2ESB to send messages to the wso2 Message Broker. I'm reading the article for [integrating the ESB to MB](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB210/Integrating+WSO2+ESB) which says to "Open /repository/conf/ JNDI.proerties file and point to the running Message Broker."

Where can I find the information on the MB side that I need to bring over to my ESB settings so that I can get this initial connection from my ESB to the Message Broker?

Edited 11/7 to provide more information

I'm using the smooks mediator (config listed below) in a proxy to try and send a message to the wso2 Message Broker (MB). I receive an exception saying that it cannot find my queue (error is below). It works when I run a simple message without smooks via the "try it" function.

I am not sure where my disconnect is. The main difference between my smooks setup and Sample proxy is that my proxy has the JMS URI posted (jms:/MyQueue?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue). I've been looking for examples and I'm not seeing where this would be set in smooks.

So my question is Can Smooks send messages to the wso2MB or does it have to be the ActiveMQ? IF it can go to wso2MB, can anyone point me in the right direction with my setup?

this value is defined in my jndi.properties files: destination="queue.MyQueue"

I have tried smooks.MyQueue, MyQueue etc. They all receive the same exception.

Thank you (Smooks Config and Exception below).

Exception

```
2015-11-07 21:37:35,456 [-] [vfs-Worker-16] ERROR SequenceMediator Error invoking @Initialize method 'initialize' on class 'org.milyn.routing.jms.JMSRouter'.
org.milyn.cdr.SmooksConfigurationException: Error invoking @Initialize method 'initialize' on class 'org.milyn.routing.jms.JMSRouter'.
    at org.milyn.cdr.annotation.Configurator.invoke(Configurator.java:457)
    at org.milyn.cdr.annotation.Configurator.initialise(Configurator.java:439)
    at org.milyn.cdr.annotation.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:91)
    at org.milyn.cdr.annotation.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:66)
    at org.milyn.delivery.JavaContentHandlerFactory.create(JavaContentHandlerFactory.java:63)
    at org.milyn.delivery.ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$ContentHandlerExtractionStrategy.addCDU(ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:623)
    at org.milyn.delivery.ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$ContentHandlerExtractionStrategy.applyCDUStrategy(ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:548)
    at org.milyn.delivery.ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$ContentHandlerExtractionStrategy.applyStrategy(ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:536)
    at org.milyn.delivery.ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$SmooksResourceConfigurationTableIterator.iterate(ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:711)
    at org.milyn.delivery.ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$SmooksResourceConfigurationTableIterator.access$300(ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:690)
    at org.milyn.delivery.ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.extractContentHandlers(ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:484)
    at org.milyn.delivery.ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.load(ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:349)
    at org.milyn.delivery.ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.getConfig(ContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:146)
    at org.milyn.container.standalone.StandaloneExecutionContext.<init>(StandaloneExecutionContext.java:91)
    at org.milyn.container.standalone.StandaloneExecutionContext.<init>(StandaloneExecutionContext.java:65)
    at org.milyn.Smooks.createExecutionContext(Smooks.java:411)
    at org.milyn.Smooks.createExecutionContext(Smooks.java:374)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.mediate(SmooksMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFSTransportListener.java:751)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:407)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:177)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:124)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.milyn.cdr.SmooksConfigurationException: NamingException while trying to lookup [queue.MyQueue]
    at org.milyn.routing.jms.JMSRouter.initialize(JMSRouter.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.milyn.cdr.annotation.Configurator.invoke(Configurator.java:453)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [queue.MyQueue] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [queue.MyQueue].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContext.lookup(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:705)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.milyn.routing.jms.JMSRouter.initialize(JMSRouter.java:207)
```

Smooks Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.3.xsd"
xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" xmlns:jb="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/javabean-1.2.xsd"
xmlns:jms="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/jms-routing-1.2.xsd" xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd">

  <core:filterSettings defaultSerialization="false" type="SAX" />

  <resource-config selector="order,order-item">
    <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
  </resource-config>

  <jb:bean beanId="row" class="java.util.Hashtable" createOnElement="row">
    <jb:value data="row/@iBookID" decoder="Integer" property="iBookID"></jb:value>
    <jb:value data="row/@vchEAN" decoder="String" property="vchEAN"></jb:value>
    <jb:value data="row/@vchISBN" decoder="String" property="vchISBN"></jb:value>
  </jb:bean>

  <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="row">
    <ftl:template>
      <!--<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
        <p:insert_Levels_AR_ISBN_operation>
            <p:iBookID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">${row.iBookID}</p:iBookID>
            <p:vchEAN xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">${row.vchEAN}</p:vchEAN>
        </p:insert_Levels_AR_ISBN_operation>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>-->
    </ftl:template>
    <ftl:use>
      <ftl:bindTo id="row_xml"/>
    </ftl:use>
  </ftl:freemarker>

  <jms:router routeOnElement="row" beanId="row_xml" destination="queue.MyQueue">
    <jms:message>
      <jms:correlationIdPattern>isbn-${row.iBookID}-${row.vchEAN}:${row.vchISBN}</jms:correlationIdPattern>
    </jms:message>
    <jms:jndi properties="/repository/conf/jndi.properties" />
    <jms:highWaterMark mark="-1" />
  </jms:router>

</smooks-resource-list>
```

Update 11/15

The port offset for the MB was +4. I have tried both port 5672 and 5676 as I think I read somewhere that this had to be increased the same number of times; neither of them worked. I have 3 queues added now and so far they all return the same error above. I recently added {create:always} to the property file. No change in it's behavior.

jndi.properties

```
# register some connection factories
# connectionfactory.[jndiname] = [ConnectionURL]
connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@carbon/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'

# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.MyQueue = MyQueue
queue.LevelsAR_ISBNService = LevelsAR_ISBNService {create:always}
queue.Levels_AR_Merge = Levels_AR_Merge {create:always}
```

Comment: I found this links which may help you. [configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/03/configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker/) [Configure with WSO2 Message Broker](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configure+with+WSO2+Message+Broker)